# What's the name of this pronunciation guide

Tags: terminology, pronunciation, phonetics, pronunciation-respelling

In dictionaries I see two guides for pronunciation. for example, for the word "ambiguity":

*[am-bi-gyoo-i-tee]* 
AND
  */ˌæmbɪˈgyuɪti/*

I know the second one is named *IPA*. My question is, is there a special name for the first one? and is there probably any difference between them?

Comment: Well, if there were a book about it, I'm sure "Pronounciation for Dummies" would be an appropriate [title](http://www.dummies.com/about-for-dummies.html) ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a pronunciation respelling system. Its advantage is that you don't have to learn it, the way you have to learn IPA. Its disadvantage is that it is good only for speakers of the language (or even the dialect) it is intended for.

Comment: A second advantage is that it *tends*, however clumsily, to represent pronunciation phonemically rather than phonetically.

Comment: @StoneyB In my experience, most dictionaries that use IPA still give only broad phonemic transcriptions, *not* narrow phonetic/phonologic ones.  That’s why they write `r` when they should use `ɹ`, etc.  [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_chart_for_English_dialects): dictionaries only give the phoneme column, not the phonetics.  Right?

Comment: @tchrist  Right. Thank you. I don't recall that distinction being in place in the 60s, when I learned IPA.

Comment: @StoneyB I didn't learn IPA till the 80s, but it wasn't always clear in dictionaries.  You can tell though that Oxford at least uses phonemic transcriptions, now if not earlier. It might be argued that they still actually have something of their own dialect in this, showing that you still have to learn the local dictionary conventions (for example, a shift in denoting secondary stress), but it is infinitely better than the effectively useless "spelling pronunciations" historically prevalent in American dictionaries.

Comment: Related Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_respelling_for_English